# Laravel showing the categories of book with pivot table error

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, backend

I am learning Laravel and i have two tables books and categories
i created a pivot table with the book_id and category_id columns to make a relationship between the tables, but when i tried to show the categories in the show book page and i made foreach on the $books->categories i faced an error saying that the foreach parameter is null

the Book model file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'desc', 'img'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
    }
}
```

the Category model file

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Book::class)->withPivot('book_category'); 
    }
}
```

the show.blade page:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('title')
    Book #{{ $book->id }}
@endsection

@section('content')
    <h2>{{ $book->title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ $book->desc }}</p>
    @foreach ($book->categories as $category)
        <span class="text-muted mx-3">{{ $category->name }}</span>
    @endforeach
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 p-5">
            <img src="{{ asset('uploads/books') }}/{{$book->img}}" class="w-100">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="{{ route('books.index') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
    <a href="{{ route('books.edit', $book->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning mx-2">Edit</a>
    <a href="{{ route('books.delete', $book->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
@endsection
```

the pivot table:

[the pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hsp1.png)

the BookController code:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $book = Book::findOrFail($id);

        return view('books/show', compact('book'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change relationship to belongsToMany since you are using pivot table.

In **Book** model

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

and in `Category`  model

```
  public function books()
  {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class); 
  }
```

In your controller

```
  $book = Book::with('categories')->findOrFail($id);
```

so in your view

```
{{$book->$title}}
@foreach ($book->categories as $category)
    <span class="text-muted mx-3">{{ $category->name }}</span>
@endforeach
```

Comment: i updated the post so you can see the show function in the controller, how can i modify it to be the same as yours?

Comment: The `has` in the Book query, will only retrieve books with at least one category, with the correction in the `belongsToMany` should return an empty array and not get any issue with the foreach.

Comment: @JuanEizmendi yes correect. if its get then we might need sometimes only to retirve those book which has category. But op updated post later so answered before that